# How to create a mnesia table with one column & read/write from/to there?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

```
-record(ng, {ng}).

mnesia:create_table(ng, [{type, set}, {attributes, record_info(fields, ng)}]).
```

I'm getting: {aborted,{bad_type,ng,{attributes,[ng]}}} error.

What's wrong? How to create a mnesia table with one column(which is named)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The record has to have at least 2 fields.  This would work:

```
-record(ng, {ng, extrafield}).
mnesia:create_table(ng, [{type, set}, {attributes, record_info(fields, ng)}]).
```

From http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#create_table-2

"The table must have at least one extra attribute in addition to the key."

Edit: Can't find an answer as to whether a single column is possible, but [this 2007 thread](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/mnesia-tables-with-few-attributes-td2101626.html) indicates not.

I personally do it with key/value columns, like this:

```
-record(proximaglobal, {key, value}).
mnesia:create_table(proximaglobal, [{attributes, record_info(fields, proximaglobal)}, {disc_only_copies, [node()]}]).
mnesia:sync_transaction(fun() -> mnesia:write(#proximaglobal{key=time, value=WorldTime}) end).
mnesia:sync_transaction(fun() -> mnesia:read(proximaglobal, time) end).
```

Answer (score 0):

> {attributes, AtomList} a list of the attribute names for the records that are supposed to populate the table. The default value is [key, val]. The table must have at least one extra attribute in addition to the key.